# i'm using html2pdf lib but i have this error Uncaught Exception

Tags: php

the error come when i try to print PDF using html2pdf lib:

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\AppDarbNajah\lib\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php:2926 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\AppDarbNajah\lib\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php(7621): TCPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\AppDarbNajah\lib\vendor\spipu\html2pdf\src\Html2Pdf.php(575): TCPDF->Output('document.pdf', 'I') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\AppDarbNajah\App\Controller\ArticleController.php(41): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->output() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\AppDarbNajah\Public\index.php(46): App\Controller\ArticleController->printlest() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\AppDarbNajah\lib\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 2926

```
 use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
 public function printlest(){
        //echo 'print';
        require_once ROOT.'/lib/vendor/autoload.php';
        $pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'en');
        $pdf->writeHTML('fffff');
        $pdf->output();
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely encountering this error because the output buffering has already started.

You can end cleanly the output buffer just before you call on the `output()` function and that should fix it for you:

```
$pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'en');
$pdf->writeHTML('fffff');
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->output();
```

Comment: No problem mate :-)

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you please mark it as Accepted

Comment: how can i make that?